let $X=[0,1]$, $\Sigma$ be a family of $|X|$ many subsets of $X$, each one of cardinality $|X|$. Is there a topology on X satisfying the following?
Let $X=[0,1]$, $\Sigma$ be a collection of continuum many subsets of $X$, each one of cardinality continuum. Does there exist a second-countable topology $\tau$ on $X$, s.t. each $\sigma \in \Sigma$ majorizes a closed set (under $\tau$) of cardinality continuum?
This question is the same as this one that I asked earlier, just restated in topological terms (curtesy of David Gao). It already has an answer there, but I'm asking the question again in the topology section to see if anyone can offer any topological insights into this question, or proofs using topological constructions.

What does "majorizes a closed set" mean.

As usual let $\mathfrak c=|I|=|\{0,1\}^\mathbb N|=2^{\aleph_0}$.
In general, if $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal, then any family $\Sigma$ consisting of $\kappa$ sets each of cardinality $\kappa$ can be refined to a collection $\Sigma'$ of $\kappa$ pairwise disjoint sets each of cardinality $\kappa$ such that each element of $\Sigma$ majorizes an element of $\Sigma'$. Hence we can assume, without loss of generality, that your collection $\Sigma$ consists of pairwise disjoint sets.
Suppose $\Sigma$ is a collection of $\mathfrak c$ pairwise disjoint sets each of cardinality $\mathfrak c$. Then there is a bijection between $\bigcup\Sigma$ and $I\times I$ such that the elements of $\Sigma$ correspond to sections $I\times\{x\}$ where $x\in I$. Therefore it will suffice to define a second-countable topology on $I\times I$ in which those sections are closed sets. The usual topology has the required properties.

This was my "simple and straightforward" answer to your previous question, which I laboriously translated into the baroque notation in which that question was presented.
